# How to reorder the menu system in Hugo

Tags: menu, hugo

I'm relatively new to Hugo and mostly just using default values. The current theme provides **Personas** and **Tags** as taxonomy categories, and they appear at the bottom of the menu system in the left navigation bar. I know how to use **weight** to change the order of the other menus, etc., but I'd like to put these taxonomy categories at the top.

I've been reading through the .toml file, Hugo docs, etc., but I'm not a coder and some of it is hard to understand. Any suggestions on how I can do this? thanks.

Using hugo-0.69.0-2.fc32~bootstrap.x86_64

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.